# Selenium RC : Button is not clicked but test passes

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a script which enters some data in the page and click save button.

Here I used HTML component id for save button.

selenium.click("StudentID:saveData");

I even provided proper wait condition and also tried with X path locator.

The test passes. It doesn't throw any error message but the button is not clicked and the data is not getting updated.

Please let me know what might be the issue .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used a CSS selector instead. CSS selectors are much faster than Xpath (and in my experience work better in general, though Xpath is necessary for certain things).

If you are using Firefox, install the Firebug add-on; right-clicking on an element on the page will give you the option to copy CSS path. I've found that I often have to make some changes to it to get it working properly but it allows you to get to very deeply nested elements quickly.

The W3C has a good page on CSS selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).